# Altering constraint in Derby

Tags: sql, derby

I don't understand the logic in Derby syntax.
I'm new to SQL, I'm learning now.
I needed to alter a column constraint.  I needed to add "not null".
Since I already did an alter on a column for the constraint unique, I thought the syntax will be the same since they are both constraints.

I finally found for not null this link [Cannot alter column in existing table in java Derby database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506777/cannot-alter-column-in-existing-table-in-java-derby-database)

and as I say the same syntax doesn't work for adding a unique constraint to the same column, so my question is: how is the syntax changed for each constraint?

This works:

```
ALTER TABLE WALLETUSER ALTER COLUMN WALLETUSERNAME NOT NULL;
```

So why does this not work?

```
ALTER TABLE WALLETUSER ALTER COLUMN WALLETUSERNAME unique;
```

And why does this work:

```
alter table customer add constraint cu1 unique (cust_name);
```

but this does not:

```
alter table customer add constraint not null (cust_name);
```

Comment: Post your code.  If it produces any errors, include them as well.

Comment: Docs are here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.13/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html